# how to do 'knife client delete' and 'knife client create' using PyChef?

Tags: python, chef-infra, pychef

What are the equivalent translations for:

```
knife client delete notcool.my.com
knife client create cool.my.com
```

in [PyChef](http://pychef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from chef import autoconfigure, Client
api = autoconfigure()
Client.delete('notcool.my.com')
Client.create('cool.my.com')
```