# PyChef-TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, chef-infra, pychef

I am newbie for using both Pychef & Chef. I want to create a script which retrieve, create, delete chef-client. I am using windows. I tried following things-

1) [how to do 'knife client delete' and 'knife client create' using PyChef?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26128891/how-to-do-knife-client-delete-and-knife-client-create-using-pychef)

2) https://pychef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html

It gives me following error-
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute **'__getitem__'**

**My questions-**

1) Is there any package I am missing on or any kind of settings/configuration?

2) https://pychef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html does not provide a brief reference as they provided for boto. Can anyone please suggest for any guidelines/urls/blogs/tutorials etc which can give brief idea about pychef

Thanks a lot !

Comment: You would need to atleast provide the code that is causing that issue including the complete traceback for the issue.

Comment: @AnandSKumar - I just tried following on python console-
>>> from chef import autoconfigure,Client
>>> api = autoconfigure()
>>> di = Client.list()

Comment: Normally that error occurs when you get `None`, but expect it to be something else and then use it without checking the result.